# Couldn't connect to selenium server to execute a webdriverIO test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

i,m having  a runtime error when i execute a webdriverIO test by console.

this is the error ***Couldn't connect to selenium server*** to execute a webdriverIO test.

I can access to my selenium server by browser (http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html) but its still not working.

Please, can anyone help me.

thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this solution?
https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/602

Specifically, adding:

`var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4444
};`

Worked for me.

Comment: done! , i have clicked in large up arrow to the left of a post, bur nothing changes, maybe my its for my reputation. thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Very long time after, but I faced this issue with Appium and I'd like to share what I find to solve it in case someone else face it with Appium.

1. Open Appium server application and start the server with host: `127.0.0.1` and port: `4723`.
2. Open your Emulator or connect device.
3. Run again the instruction to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wdio/selenium-standalone-service):

```
Handling the Selenium server is out of scope of the actual WebdriverIO project.
```

So we need to either go with raw ChromeDriver or spin up the Selenium grid. When running with the latter and setting

```
WebDriver: {
  url: '<your-vaue-here>',
  browser: 'chrome',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 4444,
  ...
```

don't forget to disable the `codecept.config.js` section, like this:

```
services: [
    ['']
],
...
```

Otherwise both servers will try to use http://localhost:4444.

**Caveat:**

When executing codeceptJS tests in parallel via `run-workers` I observe flaky behaviour as some threads actually kill the Selenium grid while others are still running. To resolve this issue, disable the `services` section and run a dedicated Grid server as initial step in your CI pipeline (assuming this is the place you actually need the parallelism).